# Issue with displaying custom tooltip on highcharts plotline labels

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have to display information on hover over the plotlines label in highcharts.

I read through the highcharts documentation and found that the tooltip can only be used with the series data.

I've tried to come up with solution by using `formatter` property.

```
    "plotLines": [{
        "color": "orange",
        "value": 1680714047143,
        "width": 2,
        "label": {
          "y": 15,
          "style": {
            "transform": "rotate(0deg)"
          },
          "enabled": true,
          "useHTML": true,
          "formatter": () => `
                <div class="label-wrapper">
                <div class="label-wrapper-title">Edit</div>
                <div class="tooltip">
                  <div class="tooltip-action">
                      Edit
                  </div>
                  <div class="tooltip-text">
                    Added these sensor notes for edit action
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            `,
        }
      },
```

```
.label-wrapper .tooltip {
    background: white;
    color: black;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: none;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: unset;
    z-index: 999;
}

.label-wrapper-title:hover + .tooltip{
    display: block;
}

.tooltip:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

Here's link to the jsfiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/sharadkalya/6eds8kLo/44/

There are two issues with this approach:

- `z-index` isn't working and text seems to overlapping each other.
- The text is not all visible inside the tooltip.

In below screenshot: I've hovered over `Edit` label to view more information (tooltip).

[image]

Is there a way to fix the above issue?
Or is there entirely different approach that can be used as an alterantive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same situation reproduced in pure HTML + CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w3vz5e7o/

As you can see, divs with `label-wrapper` class are wrapped in another element - `span` with `position: absolute` and `overflow: hidden` styles.

Using `z-index` works only for positioned elements on the same level as each other first - so you need to make the hovered spana higher z-index than the non-hovered one:

```
.highcharts-plot-line-label {
  overflow: visible !important;
}

.highcharts-plot-line-label:hover {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/v2fp395y/

Comment: Thanks @ppotaczek. But it doesn't seem to solve the second problem which is: The text is not all visible inside the tooltip.

Comment: Hi @sharad_kalya, In this case, you need to also set `overflow: visible` for chart containers. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/opfr2z8m/